# Client Secret not created on Googles developer's console

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to deploy a Xamarin.Android app using Visual Studio Community 2019 for MAC.
However, I need a Client ID and a Client Secret created before publishing the app.
I went on to googles developer's console to create a project, then try to create a Client ID and Client Secret.
The Client ID was created but not the Client Secret.
My Verification Status for the OAuth consent screen is "Verification not Required".
Is there any step that I have missed to create the Client Secret?

Comment: I guess you miss something after generated the Clinet ID. Please check the link below to check it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=windows

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT No luck. The client secret was not generated for Android Apps.
It only generated the Client ID.

Comment: Any chance you recall what the solution was?